# When might a pilot hand-fly a jet at cruise altitudes, and is it difficult?

Tags: flight-controls, jet, pilot-technique, cruise, rvsm

How difficult is it to hand-fly a jet at cruise altitudes? Other than autopilot failure and just doing it for the fun of it, when might you want to hand-fly at those altitudes?

I suspect the answer to the first question varies with different aircraft. I have an answer for the 747-100 and -200 series below.

Comment: The Lockheed U2 was extremely difficult to hand fly due to it's narrow coffin corner.

Comment: @shortstheory IS! We still use the U2!

Comment: I was a flight attendant for a major carrier and taking flying lessons back in the early 80's.  When I had about 5 hrs total time, a captain who was a friend of mine allowed me to try and hand fly a 727 at altitude from the right seat while we were over international waters. (Not that that would have mitigated the consequences if it got out what we were doing)  I couldn't do it.  The lag time between input and reaction was just too long for me to get any kind of feel for the controls. I tried for a couple minutes with him continually re-engaging the autopilot after the excursions got too big.

Comment: @PJNoes I hope he is not still an active pilot, that is absurd behaviour

Comment: @Cloud Whether that is absurd behavior is, of course, a matter of opinion. I can assure you, though, that letting flight attendants handle the controls was often done back in the 1980s and 1990s. Indeed, at the request of the captain, I vacated the f.o. seat of a 727 freighter in the late 1980s so that a jump-seating f.a. could take the controls on an approach into Barcelona, Spain in the middle of the night. The f.a. did a remarkably good job of landing the airplane, closely monitored, of course, and directed by the captain.

Comment: @Terry I presume this f.a was an aspiring pilot at least? Did you ever voice your concerns as an F.O of this practise? (p.s if you have any journal entries that detail such an event, please let me know, although I have sifted through a great deal of your website already)

Comment: @Cloud As I remember he was an Iberia f.a. working on his private license. The captain asked me if I had any objection. I did not. There's nothing about this in my journal entries because I didn't start the journal until I went to work for Tower Air, and this was back when I was flying for Evergreen International. However, I've started a topic on flying night freight in Spain, https://terryliittschwager.com/talking-of-flying.php#nightfreightspain that will include that and other things I haven't thought of in a long time.

Comment: @Terry I am very excited to read some of that! I am already in disbelief at some of the titles... "Valencia to Madrid speed competition", "drunk loaders"... oh dear...:)

Answer (score 36):

For 747-100 and -200 aircraft at 35,000 ft and above, you can do it, but it's hard to keep the airplane within 100 feet of the assigned altitude, and you typically can't do that (or at least I couldn't) without practice. 200 foot altitude excursions were the norm when I first took control if I had not done it for a while. For the few first officers that accepted an invitation to try it, an initial 300 foot altitude excursion was typical when they first tried it, especially immediately after disengaging the autopilot.

I found the concentration required was very tiring. Ten minutes was typically enough to satisfy the urge.

Insofar as when you might want to do it, I found hand-flying produced a smoother ride in heavy to severe turbulence than the autopilot's turbulence mode, which tended to try to keep the assigned altitude and aircraft pitch too slavishly.

Comment: Are you even allowed to do it now there is RVSM?

Comment: @JanHudec No, handflying is off limits in RVSM airspace.

Comment: It helps a **lot** if you have a good flight director with altitude capture and hold.  Then it isn't quite as big of a deal, though it is still tiring because of the constant concentration that it requires. In the past when an autopilot has failed, I would take turns with the other pilot and we would only fly for 15 minutes at a time.

Comment: @janhudec See: [Is it legal to fly in RVSM airspace with an inoperative autopilot?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-it-legal-to-fly-in-rvsm-airspace-with-an-inoperative-autopilot/162#162)

Comment: @Lnafziger Using a flight director is cheating! lol

Although I suppose one could say that using the artificial horizon is cheating and one should do it simply by outside visual reference. I tried that once and it simply didn't work for me.

Comment: @Terry Haha, he just said hand-fly so a flight director is allowed!  :-)  And yeah, maintaining altitude by outside visual references is basically impossible at that altitude and speed.  If you are 1/2 a degree of pitch off, you will be way off your altitude before you even know it...

Comment: @DeltaLima  At the risk of being pedantic, hand-flying IS allowed in RVSM airspace, just not while level.  The rules allow you to climb or descent without the autopilot since "precise altitude control" isn't happening, or even being attempted, when you're following a climb or descent clearance.  For level flight, though, the autopilot is required to be engaged in RVSM airspace (with exceptions as noted in Lnafziger's linked answer).

Comment: "an initial 300 foot altitude excursion was typical when they first tried it, especially immediately after disengaging the autopilot" - Wouldn't an altitude excursion immediately upon disengaging the autopilot be more a symptom of a slightly-out-of-trim airplane?

Comment: @Vikki We would start the exercise with the aircraft in-trim. The 747-100/200 series had a small window that showed how much elevator the autopilot was holding against the trim, and you could hand-roll the big trim wheel to align the pointers. As I remember if I was in practice the altitude excursion when disengaging the autopilot was negligible. You're right, though, that if you didn't start with the airplane trimmed, the nose-down would be immediate and could be substantial. I used this fact in a Toastmasters humorous speech at https://terryliittschwager.com/hajj4contest.php.

Answer (score 13):

It's probably not a good idea to hand fly jets at cruise altitudes in many cases ([US](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/air_traffic_services/rvsm/documentation/#large), [EU](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Reduced_Vertical_Separation_Minima_%28RVSM%29), and others). The reason is that from FL290 to FL410 (29,000 to 41,000 feet standard pressure altitude), a lot of airspace is under [RVSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_vertical_separation_minima) rules (Reduced vertical separation minima).

This means that aircraft are only separated by 1000 feet vertically. One of the requirements for flying in RVSM airspace is a system for automatically maintaining altitude. If this system is not working, either the aircraft must fly at an altitude outside RVSM space (most likely below) or ATC must agree to provide 2000 foot separation above and below from other traffic.

Some examples of this in practice:

- [Allowed to continue with increased separation](http://avherald.com/h?article=45237903)
- [Not allowed to continue, had to return to airport](http://avherald.com/h?article=463e0a88)
- [Did not inform ATC in violation of rules](http://avherald.com/h?article=4694c940)

See the related question for more details:

[Is it legal to fly in RVSM airspace with an inoperative autopilot?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-it-legal-to-fly-in-rvsm-airspace-with-an-inoperative-autopilot)

Comment: You can legally do it at FL430 or above though!

Comment: So you can handfly the supersonic Concorde at cruise? YEAHH!

Answer (score 11):

Aerodynamic damping is proportional to density, so all maneuvers require less control input at altitude than near the ground. On the downside, excursions from the trimmed condition produce greater amplitudes before stability pulls the aircraft back. This explains why hand-flying needs more attention at high altitude.

Background: Damping is the reaction of a system to movement, and positive damping means the reaction slows the movement down. Case in point: The horizontal tail. When the pitch attitude changes (say, by a vertical gust which changes lift first on the wing, then on the horizontal tail), the rotation of the aircraft around the Y axis (the one pointing sideways) creates an additional vertical speed on the horizontal tail surface. This vertical speed is proportional to pitch speed (obviously) and the distance between c.g. and tail. This speed changes the local angle of attack by the ratio between the vertical speed and flight speed. Now we are at the core of it: A high flight speed will cause a smaller angle of attack change at the tail for the same pitch rate. Since this angle of attack change creates the damping force (by creating lift on the tail which counteracts the pitch movement), a higher flight speed at the same dynamic pressure will lead to less damping. This is a fancy way of saying that flying in lower density air makes the aircraft more responsive to disturbances.

Comment: AF 447 was a case of the autopilot dumping control into the laps of the pilots, at cruise altitude and speed, and they managed to put the aircraft into a fatal high speed stall. At cruise, aircraft will often be fairly close to the edge of the envelope, and, as @PeterKämpf mentioned, you've really got to pay attention to what you're doing, so you don't end up on the wrong side of the limits.

Comment: No, Phil, that was an ordinary low speed stall. A high speed stall happens when Mach effects limit the lift coefficient to values below what is required to create sufficient lift. And the cruise altitude of airliners is limited by engine power - they are not (yet) flying in the "coffin corner". Yes, the envelope is smaller, but mostly because of limited thrust.

Comment: Sorry, I've frequently heard this case described as a "high speed stall", but maybe everyone saying that is wrong. They had what would normally be considered plenty of airspeed, but raised the nose way too high and stalled as a result. Would that still be considered a "low speed" stall even though they were (AIUI) still at more or less cruising speed?

Comment: Yes, this is low speed stall because the dynamic pressure was not high enough to allow the aircraft to fly properly. The angle of attack was well into the stall region, large sections of the wing had separated flow and the drag that goes with it. This drag caused the high sink rate which made AF447 sink from cruise altitude to sea level in just three minutes. They arrived there at the same dynamic pressure at which they started the descent, and then the aircraft was flying really slowly, too.